# Elixir: How to deal with optional / default parameters in functions and nil values?

Tags: elixir

I have a general question about default parameters and nil values. Suppose I have two functions. One calls the other (which is a helper function). Both have an optional parameter.

The helper function just joins a list to a string with a joiner. The joiner is passed to the first function inside an opts keyword list. The passing of the joiner is optional, it defaults to `"AND"`

```
defmodule ParamTest do
  def func_1(list, opts \\ []) do
    helper(list, opts[:joiner])
    # Do something else with the result
  end

  defp helper(list, joiner \\ "AND") do
    Enum.join(list, " #{joiner} ")
  end
end

# Example 1
["el 1", "el 2"] 
|> ParamTest.func_1(joiner: "AND")
# Result "el 1 AND el 2"

# Example 2
["el 1", "el 2"] 
|> ParamTest.func_1
# Result: "el 1  el 2"
# But it should be also "el 1 AND el 2"
```

The problem is: opts[:joiner] will be nil in the second example. But it is still present so the default value will not be used.

One possible solution would be to use `case`:

```
defmodule ParamTest do
  def func_1(list, opts \\ []) do
    case is_nil(opts[:joiner]) do
      true -> helper(list)
      false -> helper(list, opts[:joiner])
    end
    # Do something else with the result
  end

  defp helper(list, joiner \\ "AND") do
    Enum.join(list, " #{joiner} ")
  end
end
```

Another way would be to use two function definitions for helper and use pattern matching:

```
defmodule ParamTest do
  def func_1(list, opts \\ []) do
    case is_nil(opts[:joiner]) do
      true -> helper(list)
      false -> helper(list, opts[:joiner])
    end
  end

  defp helper(list, nil) do
    Enum.join(list, " AND ")
  end

  defp helper(list, joiner \\ "AND") do
    Enum.join(list, " #{joiner} ")
  end
end
```

But I have the feeling that this is not very elegant and could get messy in more complex situations.

What is a better solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No better solution that what you already have in my opinion. Personally, I would ask myself the following questions:

- am I sure I need a default argument for the `helper/2` *private* function? I'm not confident about this, but I feel like default `\\` args to private function may be some kind of code smell.
- where do I want to handle the complexity if I go with a `\\` default argument? :)

If I had to choose, in this particular case I'd probably go with calling `helper/1` and `helper/2` separately, based on the presence of the `:joiner` option:

```
defmodule ParamTest do
  def func_1(list, opts \\ []) do
    if joiner = opts[:joiner] do
      helper(list, joiner)
    else
      helper(list)
    end
  end

  defp helper(list, joiner \\ "AND") do
    Enum.join(list, " #{joiner} ")
  end
end
```

However, as I stated above, since `helper/2` is a private function it may make sense (depending on your use case, this one is too small for us to make a more thoughtful decision :P) to move the optional joiner completely to the boundary of the "system", i.e., just to `func_1/2` by using a default value for the option:

```
defmodule ParamTest do
  def func_1(list, opts \\ []) do
    helper(list, opts[:joiner] || "AND")
  end

  defp helper(list, joiner) do
    Enum.join(list, " #{joiner} ")
  end
end
```

Again, this may not scale well in your use case but I feel like it's the best we can do with the information we have from the question :).

Comment: I agree with the default argument for private functions. And I like your second solution. Thanks.

Comment: If the helper is only going to be called from the first function then having double defaults is awkward. The second solution is awkward because you have the || inside the function call. You are better off just having your default be opts \\ [joiner: "AND"]

Comment: @CaptChrisD as other people pointed out in the comments to the other function, `[joiner: "AND"]` as a default *usually* is not a good idea as the function can accept many options (it's rare that a function only accepts one option).

Answer (score 10):

The best solution would be to make joiner mandatory in helper and provide default options in `func_1`.

```
def func_1(list, opts \\ [joiner: "AND"]) do
  helper(list, opts[:joiner])
  ...
end
defp helper(list, joiner) do
  ...
end
```

Always try to separate your concerns. `helper` is not part of your public API, so you can always pass all the options. Let it just do its work and not worry about defaults.

`func_1` is your public API and it should worry about defaults. You want to specify "AND" joiner by default, so do it instead of defaulting to empty option list. When developers read your code, they won't need to go deeper to check where does the "AND" come from and can easily figure out, that they can pass this option without reading docs or even function body.

It is usually a good idea to have defaults only for convenience at top level functions (the API) and just pass explicitly everything down. Otherwise, you would have to check at each level, if the option was passed like you did in your example with `case`. This is error prone.

Comment: I even like your version even more than the one by @whatyouhide since it makes the default very clear to someone reading my code for the first time. Thanks

Comment: I have to retract my previous statement. As soon as more options are passed in with the opts argument, everything is overwritten and this solution doesn't work anymore. `["el 1", "el 2"] |> ParamTest.func_1(something: "whatever")` will produce `"el 1  el 2"`

Comment: You are right. In case, you have more options and you want to override only some of them, `opts[:joiner] || "AND"` is better. Alternatively in first lines of function you can do `opts = opts ++ [joiner: "AND"]`, but this makes sense  only if all options have defaults and there is couple of them.